# how to replace strings in postgresql by using regular expression?

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, replace, pattern-matching

t.emailAddresses contains comma separated email addresses.

I want to replace some email address with '0', how can I do it with regular expression ?

I wrote it with replace(), but i want to write it in regex wayemailAddresses

```
SELECT t.emailAddresses,
       replace (replace (replace (replace (t.emailAddresses,
         'jack@example.com', '0'), 'jack@mybox.com', '0'), 'emly@example.com',
         '0'), 'emly@mybox.com', '0') as replaced_email_address
FROM table t
WHERE t.id = 100;
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The general regex syntax for replacing something would be:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, $rxb$^jack@example\.com$$rxb$, $$0$$, 'g') FROM mytable;
```

But...

- If you're replacing a literal (something that doesn't change, there's no point.
- It's useful if you want to maybe replace an email that starts with `jack`

For example,

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(mycolumn, $$^jack.*$$, $$0$$, 'g') FROM mytable;
```